# Restrict number of Foreign keys relations in Django

Tags: django

Is it possible to have max number of relations by foreign key in django?

For example, I want to have no more than 10 posts made by one user. I init the model

```
class Post(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

where should I add this check? Or it's not possible and I should make it in view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how i would do this.

Each model has a save() option that is called when the model is saved. You can check here and raise an error if the user already has 10 posts.

```
class Post(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    def save(self,*args, **kwargs):
        if self.id == None: #Creating a new object
            if Post.objects.filter(owner=self.owner).count() >= 10:
                #Raise whatever error you want or just return false
        return super(Post, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Are you sure, that in Model `save()` you can access `request`?

Comment: @Headmaster replace request.user with self.owner